# Pacman Ghost class, what does this method do?

Tags: java, methods, pacman

I dont understand what the method moveGhost does? Why pick a random number between 0-7 and what does that have to do with chasing pacman?
Oh, and what can I do to create a GUI image of the ghost?
I found this code and am trying to understand how it works.

```
public class GhostRed {

private int size;
private int row, col;

//constructor
public GhostRed(int r, int c, int s) {
    row = r;
    col = c;
    size = s;

}

public int getRow() {
    return row;
}
public int getCol() {
    return col;
}
public void setRow(int r) {
    row = r;

}
public void setCol(int c) {
    col = c;
}

private boolean checkMove(int r, int c) {
    boolean check=true;
    if (r<0 || r > size-1 || c < 0 || c > size-1) {
        check= false;
    }
    return check;
}

public boolean moveGhost() {

    boolean move=true;
    Random r = new Random();
    int newMove = r.nextInt(7); //taking a random number btw 0-7


    if (newMove == 0) {
        if(checkMove(row-1, col)==false) {
        move=false;
        }
        else{
        row = row-1;
        }

    }
    if (newMove == 1) {
        if(checkMove(row+1, col)==false) {
        move= false;
        }
        else{
        row = row+1;
        }

    }
    if (newMove == 2) {
        if(checkMove(row, col-1)==false) {
        move= false;
        }else{
        col = col-1;
        }

    }
    if (newMove == 3) {
        if(checkMove(row, col+1)==false) {
        move= false;
        }
        else{
        col = col+1;
        }

    }
    if (newMove == 4) {
        if(checkMove(row-1, col-1)==false) {
        move= false;
        }
        else{
        row = row-1;
        col = col-1;
        }

    }
    if (newMove == 5) {
        if(checkMove(row-1, col+1)==false) {
        move= false;
        }
        else{
        row = row-1;
        col = col+1;
        }

    }
    if (newMove == 6) {
        if(checkMove(row+1, col-1)==false) {
        move= false;
        }
        else{
        row = row+1;
        col = col-1;
        }

    }
    if (newMove == 7) {
        if(checkMove(row+1, col+1)==false) {
        move= false;
        }else{
        row = row+1;
        col = col+1;
        }

    }

    return move;


}
```

}

Answer (score 3):

The `moveGhost` method moves the ghost in a random direction from the 8 compass-directions (N, S, E, W, NW, SW, NE, NW). The eight different directions correspond to the 8 different numbers in the range 0-7.

If the method `checkMove` returns false then the ghost doesn't move.